# Query using COUNT returns records where the count is positive only

Tags: sql, sqlite, count

Good day everyone.

Consider this portion of a relational SQLite database:

**floors**(number) - **rooms**(number, #floorNumber)

I aim to query for the number of rooms per floor. This is my attempt:

```sql
select floors.number, count(rooms.floornumber)
from floors, rooms where floors.number=rooms.floornumber
group by floors.number, rooms.floornumber;
```

Example:

```
1|5
2|7
3|5
4|3
```

The issue is that I also would like the query to return records where the floor contains 0 rooms (for example floor number 5 exists in the "floors" table but isn't shown in the query result).

Your assistance is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

You need a `LEFT JOIN`, but you cannot even see what you need because of the way that your query is written.

```
select f.number, count(r.floornumber)
from floors f left join
     rooms r
     on f.number = r.floornumber
group by f.number;
```

Comment: Understood. Thank you for your advice.